# why IP of docker container changes after restart it?

Tags: docker, ip, containers, restart

It is default way that the IP of a docker container will change after restarting it. I am confused why this is suggested in designing docker. Is it more reasonable to retain the IP with a simple restart? This should be distinguished from creating a new container.

Answer (score 0):

IP of a docker container gets changed after a restart as of now, but the community is working [here](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork) on this highly demanded feature. Meanwhile I am using [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) to assign specific IP to my docker container.

```
pipework docker-bridge-name-here docker-container-name 10.1.1.110/24@10.1.1.1
```

The only drawback is that you'll have to do it every time you restart docker.